# Filtering out some rows

Tags: mysql, sql, filtering

I'd like to filter out some rows in SQL. This is my table.

```
ID | year
1 2002
1 2003
2 2003
2 2004
3 2002
```

I'd like to filter the ID's that has got a 2003 in the year column. 
That means in this case, there will be no ID's that has got 2003 in the year column.
What is the SQL code I should use?

Comment: Have you tried anything? maybe something like ``year != 2003``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list all IDs that do not have a 2003 in the year column then `year != 2003`, as it was suggested by other users, won't be enough because that will return `id = 2` as it contains `2004` too.

A good approach is to list get all IDs and remove from them the ones that contain `2003` in the year. You can do that this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id FROM t
  WHERE YEAR = 2003
)
```

This will **only output** `id = 3`.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77b4ab/1).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd0d6/3

```
  select id
from dateyear
where year<> 2003
group by id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous.  One interpretation is to get the list of ids that do not contain the year 2003:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having sum(year = 2003) = 0
```

Comment: Have you tried the query? it doesn't appear to work see: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/959ac7/1 with your query